Git Push Not Updating Remote
I'm not sure what happened but I'm suddenly not able to push my changes to the remote branch.
On branch qas
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/qas' by 110 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

I run "git push"  and it tells me:
Everything up-to-date 

If I run git status it shows:
On branch qas

Your branch is ahead of 'origin/qas' by 110 commits.

  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

As far as I'm concerned I would be just as happy deleting the qas branch on the remote and just pushing what is on my machine. The way we operate is we have a development branch, a qas branch, and a production branch. I merge development into qas, and then when ready, qas into production. There is no development that goes on in the qas or production branches.
What is the best way to get my qas changes into the remote qas branch?
EDIT: Here is the output from "git remote show origin" and "git branch -v -v"
    **git remote show origin**
    * remote origin
      Fetch URL: <my git repository>.git
      Push  URL: <<my git repository>.git
      HEAD branch: master
      Remote branches:
        angularUpgrade                                       tracked
        ctburndownimsidupdates                               tracked
        dashboardfix                                         tracked
        development                                          tracked
        fiscal_month                                         tracked
        lee-demo                                             tracked
        master                                               tracked
        new_tbx                                              tracked
        production                                           tracked
        qas                                                  tracked
        sword-all-scorecards-troubleshoot                    tracked
        sword-coe-ct-burndown-troubleshoot                   tracked
        sword-coe-health-metric-scorecard-adding-drill-downs tracked
        sword-coe-health-metric-scorecard-fixing-errors      tracked
        sword-coe-scorecard-troubleshoot                     tracked
        sword-ct-battlefield                                 tracked
        sword-ct-burndown-ims                                tracked
        sword-cycle-time-chart                               tracked
        sword-data-delivery                                  tracked
        sword-data-delivery-filter                           tracked
        sword-defect-density                                 tracked
        sword-greg-changes                                   tracked
        sword-iet-scorecard                                  tracked
        sword-iet-scorecard-adding-drill-downs               tracked
        sword-ior-charts                                     tracked
        sword-lob-coe-scorecard-adding-drill-downs           tracked
        sword-lob-program-related-scorecards-troubleshoot    tracked
        sword-on-time-12mo-forecast-mod                      tracked
        sword-program-baseline-scorecard                     tracked
        sword-rfc-count                                      tracked
        sword-rfc-count-coe                                  tracked
        sword-rfc-count-filter                               tracked
        sword-rfc-count-integration-redo                     tracked
        sword-scorecard-troubleshoot                         tracked
        sword-space-rollup-scorecard-adding-drilldowns       tracked
        sword-space-rollup-scorecard-troubleshoot            tracked
        sword-tbx-burndown-add-mappingdata                   tracked
        sword-tbx-burndown-change-pdr-cdr-data-source        tracked
        sword-tbx-on-time-updates                            tracked
        sword-tbx-summary-data                               tracked
        tbx_chart_updates_for_pam                            tracked
      Local branches configured for 'git pull':
        ctburndownimsidupdates                     merges with remote ctburndownimsidupdates
        dashboardfix                               merges with remote dashboardfix
        development                                merges with remote development
        fiscal_month                               merges with remote fiscal_month
        lee-demo                                   merges with remote lee-demo
        master                                     merges with remote master
        new_tbx                                    merges with remote new_tbx
        production                                 merges with remote production
        qas                                        merges with remote qas
        sword-all-scorecards-troubleshoot          merges with remote sword-all-scorecards-troubleshoot     
        sword-coe-ct-burndown-troubleshoot         merges with remote sword-coe-ct-burndown-troubleshoot    
        sword-ct-battlefield                       merges with remote sword-ct-battlefield
        sword-ct-burndown-ims                      merges with remote sword-ct-burndown-ims
        sword-greg-changes                         merges with remote sword-greg-changes
        sword-lob-coe-scorecard-adding-drill-downs merges with remote sword-lob-coe-scorecard-adding-drill-downs
        sword-on-time-12mo-forecast-mod            merges with remote sword-on-time-12mo-forecast-mod       
        sword-program-baseline-scorecard           merges with remote sword-program-baseline-scorecard      
        sword-rfc-count                            merges with remote sword-rfc-count
        sword-rfc-count-filter                     merges with remote sword-rfc-count-filter
        sword-rfc-count-integration-redo           merges with remote sword-rfc-count-integration-redo      
        sword-tbx-on-time-updates                  merges with remote sword-tbx-on-time-updates
        tbx_chart_updates_for_pam                  merges with remote tbx_chart_updates_for_pam
      Local refs configured for 'git push':
        ctburndownimsidupdates                     pushes to ctburndownimsidupdates                     (up to date)
        dashboardfix                               pushes to dashboardfix                               (up to date)
        development                                pushes to development                                (up to date)
        fiscal_month                               pushes to fiscal_month                               (up to date)
        lee-demo                                   pushes to lee-demo                                   (up to date)
        master                                     pushes to master                                     (up to date)
        new_tbx                                    pushes to new_tbx                                    (up to date)
    to date)
        sword-on-time-12mo-forecast-mod            pushes to sword-on-time-12mo-forecast-mod            (up to date)
        sword-program-baseline-scorecard           pushes to sword-program-baseline-scorecard           (up to date)
        sword-rfc-count                            pushes to sword-rfc-count                            (up to date)
        sword-rfc-count-filter                     pushes to sword-rfc-count-filter                     (up to date)
        sword-rfc-count-integration-redo           pushes to sword-rfc-count-integration-redo           (up to date)
        sword-tbx-on-time-updates                  pushes to sword-tbx-on-time-updates                  (up to date)
        tbx_chart_updates_for_pam                  pushes to tbx_chart_updates_for_pam                  (up to date)


    **git branch -v -v**
      QAS                                        efa5756 Merge branch 'development' into QAS
      ctburndownimsidupdates                     03c6cdb [origin/ctburndownimsidupdates] Added IMSID Change order Burndown
      dashboardfix                               41ae4a9 [origin/dashboardfix] Add Excel Export to Q-Notes
      development                                460844b [origin/development] TBx chart updates
      fiscal_month                               eb5399d [origin/fiscal_month] Added Excel and images
      lee-demo                                   9bb0c36 [origin/lee-demo] I made changes
      master                                     bd02d98 [origin/master] Initial Push
      new_tbx                                    6ac1bc3 [origin/new_tbx] Initial TBX Charts and Tables - Lee
      production                                 3d99828 [origin/production: ahead 2] Merge branch 'development' into production
    * qas                                        25da205 [origin/qas: ahead 110] Merge branch 'development' into qas
      sword-all-scorecards-troubleshoot          3f050fc [origin/sword-all-scorecards-troubleshoot: behind 3] Merge branch 'sword-lob-program-related-scorecards-troubleshoot' into sword-all-scorecards-troubleshoot       
      sword-coe-ct-burndown-troubleshoot         5d7777c [origin/sword-coe-ct-burndown-troubleshoot] deleted console.logs
      sword-ct-battlefield                       a4682d9 [origin/sword-ct-battlefield] updates to battle field view
      sword-ct-burndown-ims                      2f8d1ac [origin/sword-ct-burndown-ims: ahead 24] Merge branch 'development' into sword-ct-burndown-ims
      sword-greg-changes                         2fa24f1 [origin/sword-greg-changes] FIxed program Selection
      sword-lob-coe-scorecard-adding-drill-downs b9959b9 [origin/sword-lob-coe-scorecard-adding-drill-downs] Merge branch 'development' into sword-lob-coe-scorecard-adding-drill-downs
      sword-on-time-12mo-forecast-mod            88edc46 [origin/sword-on-time-12mo-forecast-mod] Merge branch 'development' into sword-on-time-12mo-forecast-mod
      sword-program-baseline-scorecard           f352801 [origin/sword-program-baseline-scorecard] html update
      sword-rfc-count                            b49bd19 [origin/sword-rfc-count] Merge branch 'development' into sword-rfc-count
      sword-rfc-count-filter                     9983f7b [origin/sword-rfc-count-filter] Updated sizing
      sword-rfc-count-integration-redo           8df3b3f [origin/sword-rfc-count-integration-redo] Merge branch 'sword-rfc-count-integration-redo' of <my git repository> into sword-rfc-count-integration-redo
      sword-tbx-on-time-updates                  25cea19 [origin/sword-tbx-on-time-updates] tbx updates
      tbx_chart_updates_for_pam                  460844b [origin/tbx_chart_updates_for_pam] TBx chart updates


Do you host your repositories on your own servers? If so, did you recently update git? What version?

Please add the output of git remote show origin to your post.

Please also show the output of git branch -v -v and inspect the output of git log --graph --oneline --decorate qas origin/qas. There's not really enough information here to answer the question yet.

We host our own repositories. No recent updates that I'm aware of. I've been able to push the development branch without error. Is there a way I can delete the QAS branch on the remote and just push this new version?

Can you run git fetch and check if your branch is still ahead?

Git fetch doesn't change anything. Can I run: git push origin qas -f  and just overwrite the remote branch and be done with this?

@FlyFish: you can do whatever you want but be aware that this most likely isn't a bug in Git and that for some reason you're really ahead of remote. Maybe this branch has 2 different remote branches configured for pull and push?

This is really weird. I ended up doing ANOTHER merge of development into qas. I was then able to push to git. So the problem is fixed, but I don't know why.

My understanding is that your qas branch is out of sync with the origin
I would try to debug and resolve the state, by investigate the logs.
git fetch
git log origin/qas --oneline
git log qas --oneline

Maybe it shows you why git is confused.
If you know that you don’t need the other branch current state and don’t care that others may hate you, you can always force =)

I'm the only person who does anything with these branches other than development, so I really do not care. I tried git push --force and it did nothing.

Please review the logs to understand what happened, then run a pull to verify that everything is up to date and proceed again with git push origin/qas
It is recalled that from the terminal the procedure to be followed is git add . git commit -m "commit" and then you can push.

The git pull, add, and commit were done and had no effect. What is interesting, and I'm not a git expert, but I get a fatal error running git push origin/qas. 'origin/qas' does not appear to be a git repository Could not read from remote repository. I don't get this error with just a git push
